# How to use jquery .show() to apply a function in the same parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a simple jQuery show function to reveal class .show-more when a user clicks on the div .ask-more:

```
<div class="participant" id="participant-1">

<div class="ask-more"></div>
<div class="show-more" style="display:none"></div>

</div>

<div class="participant" id="participant-2">

<div class="ask-more"></div>
<div class="show-more" style="display:none"></div>

</div>
```

I have the following code (which works):

```
$( ".ask-more" ).click(function() {
  $( ".show-more" ).show();
});
```

My question: at present this function shows the class for both participant ids; how can I adapt the script so that only the .show-more class in the same parent as the .ask-more class that is clicked on is revealed? I.e. click ask-more in #participant-1 div and only show-more in #participant-1 is revealed, not both.

Please note, I don't want to use individual #participant-1/2 references, as I need this to scale hundreds of times. I am essentially asking for a relative lookup in jQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .siblings() as follows:

```
$(this).siblings(".show-more").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".ask-more").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".show-more").show(); // or $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `show-more` is the next sibling element, you you can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next) to fetch that element

```
$( ".ask-more" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
});
```